# color not shown on print preview but shown on simple view

Tags: html, css

I am new in css and making a preview voucher for printing.
Classes that i using are working correctly on simple view but not working on print preview like.

[image]

print Preview

[image]

this is css code

```
.titlebar{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(to bottom, #03320E 25%, #273E29 76%) repeat scroll 0 0;
    color:#ffffff}
```

same code in

```
@media print{
  .titlebar{
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(to bottom, #03320E 25%, #273E29 76%) repeat scroll 0 0;
     color:#ffffff}
```

}

here my header files that i am including.
    assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    
    assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

```
<!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins 
     folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
 <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/bootstrap-daterangepicker-master/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/fileinput.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/dist/css/AdminLTE.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and css style code is in AdminLTE.css.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers dont show background-color as standard. You need to make your browser print with background-colors too, in the settings.
This is to prevent pages from using up a lot of ink, when printed.

In Chrome, for example, you need to press "Advanced settings" and check the checkbox for Background Graphics.

Comment: it shows background for some tages but not for this

Answer (score 0):

try this,

Add media attribute in the link tag,  it will work.

```
<link media="print" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/bootstrap-daterangepicker-master/daterangepicker.css"  type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.titlebar{
   width: 100%;
   height: 55px;
   background: #03320E;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) -webkit-linear-gradient(#03320E 25%, #273E29 76%) repeat scroll 0 0;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) -o-linear-gradient(#03320E 25%, #273E29 76%) repeat scroll 0 0;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(#03320E 25%, #273E29 76%) repeat scroll 0 0;
      color:#ffffff;
  }
  @media print{
   body {
       -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
   }
  }
```

```html
<div class="titlebar"></div>
```

Please add below code inside @media print{}

```
body {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
}
```

Comment: after that result same as like before using this "Not working"

Comment: I have tested with a demo sample it is working perfectly fine. Please have a look.